# Flutter sending a post request to a Django API with a file as the body

Tags: django, file, flutter, dart, http-post

I have a Django API where a user is able to upload a file through a post request with the following body:

```
{
  "file": *attached file*
}
```

In Django, the file is gathered from the request with `request.FILES['file']`

The request has to be sent from flutter (dart) code. I have tried a few ways, this is the function from my latest attempt which shows an error - because the "file" is not in the correct format.

```
static void uploadProfilePhoto(File file, String fileId) async {
    Uint8List fileBytes = file.readAsBytesSync();
    var response = http.post(
      globals.baseURL() + "/upload/",
      //headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: {
        "file":base64Encode(fileBytes)
      }
    ).then((v)=>print("v: "+v.body));
  }
```

Any idea in what format the "file" should be sent from flutter? Else is there any other method which might work? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you find a way to send the file ?

Comment: @MrunalJoshi sadly not, we found a workaround this using firebase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in flutter use

```
import 'dart:convert' as convert;
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

  @override
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> sendFiletodjango(
      {File file,
    }) async {
    var endPoint = url;
    Map data = {};
    String base64file = base64Encode(file.readAsBytesSync());
    String fileName = file.path.split("/").last;
    data['name']=fileName;
    data['file']= base64file;
    try {
      var response = await http.post(endPoint,headers: yourRequestHeaders, body:convert.json.encode(data));
    } catch (e) {
      throw (e.toString());
    }
  }
```

in python django use

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile



file = response.data.get("file")
name = response.data.get("name")

your_file = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(file),name)

model.fileField = your_file
model.save()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately i cannot modify the django code, you think there is any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `multipart/form-data` to upload files from Flutter to the Django server using HTTP `post` request.

From flutter, you can send `multipart/form-data` request in the below shown way.

```
Future<Response> uploadFile(File file) async {
  Response response;
  var uri = Uri.parse(url);
  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
  request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file', file.path));
  var response = await request.send();
  if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
    print('Uploaded!');
  }
  return response;
}
```

You can find more about it here [Dart MultipartRequest](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html).

Comment: If you are using `django-rest-framework` and having `models.FileField` in model, in `post` request, file upload will work using `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Sadly this didnt work for me, think its because there is no rest framework for it, its just using request.FILES in django. Any idea how that may apply to this?

Comment: Please try your `post` api using `multipart/form-data` in postman and see if it's working.

Comment: @HassanAnsari Please try your `post` api using `multipart/form-data` in postman and see if it's working.